Icon Doesn't Appear for MAUI Blazor App on Windows if Taskbar Icons are Combined
I'm currently working on a MAUI Blazor app that needs to run on Windows and Android, and am running into an issue with the App Icon on Windows.
I can get it to populate through specifying the image in the Program file and the title in the MauiProgram.cs file, but when a user's settings are set to combine taskbar buttons, the app is just a blank space on the taskbar instead of the image and title combination.
Is it possible to keep this app from being combinable on the taskbar or force that image with that "combine buttons" setting still on and if so, how would I set this?  If this isn't doable at the program level, is there a way to accomplish this on the device?
I've specified the icon sizes in the manifest for the app and they appear correctly if the "Combine Taskbar Buttons" option is set to "Never" or "When Taskbar Is Full" but this defaults to a blank space when collapsed.
This is the XML for the section of the Package.appxmanifest file:
  <Applications>
    <Application Id="App" Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe" EntryPoint="$targetentrypoint$">
      <uap:VisualElements
        DisplayName="Display Lookup"
        Description="Display Lookup"
        Square150x150Logo="Resources\Images\icon.png"
        Square44x44Logo="Resources\Images\icon.png"
        BackgroundColor="black">
        <uap:DefaultTile Square71x71Logo="Resources\Images\icon.png" Wide310x150Logo="Resources\Images\icon.png" Square310x310Logo="Resources\Images\icon.png"  ShortName="icon"/>
        <uap:LockScreen BadgeLogo="Resources\Images\BadgeLogo.png" Notification="badge"/>
      </uap:VisualElements>
    </Application>
  </Applications>



How did you create the combine taskbar buttons？ Can you provide the relevant code?

This is an option in the taskbar settings menu for Windows 10 and 11. I believe that the default value for "Combine Taskbar Buttons" is "Always, Hide Labels".

Yes, this is a setting based on the Windows system and cannot be changed through the Maui Blazor project. I tested the default Maui Blazor project and found that the icon can be displayed normally regardless of whether the label is expanded or collapsed. So, I think the setting of the project name and icon in the .csproj file causes the problem. Please provide the code for the project name and icon in the .csproj file. Did you try to set the icon to .svg format?

It looks like it's grabbing it from the Windows/Package.appxmanifest file and not the project file.  I did try adjusting the values in that project file which did not affect the taskbar icon, whereas updating the package does. That file doesn't allow me to set svgs, only jpg and png. I've updated the original post with that section of the Package.appxmanifest file

In MAUI, if you want to change the app icon, just delete the previous icon in the Project > Resources > AppIcon, and add your new icon image to this folder, then set its Property > Build Action to MauiIcon.
So it is not necessary to change the icon related code in the Package.appxmanifest file.
You can try the following steps to set the icon:

Restore the code in Package.appxmanifest to the default code.
Check if the Property of the icon file in Project-> Resources -> AppIcon is set to MauiIcon
Check if the  section in the .csproj file is set correctly:


MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\icon.png" />

For more settings about app icon, you can refer to Change the icon

Thank you for your help, this was correct, but in addition to that, I needed to comment out the references to the icon in the Windows Package.appxmanifest file that I had posted earlier.  This prevented it from being overwritten by a file which didn't work correctly.
